# Is it a good practice to return a map or list as HTTP response

Tags: rest, http, http-response

The result of processing an HTTP request consists of mappings. Each mapping is from an order number to an object. Is it a good practice to return this as an HTTP response whose body is a Map<String, Object>? How about a List where the object contains the order number string as an attribute. If none of these is a good practice, how should the response look like? How are these options, from a RESTfulness perspective?

Comment: "Good" in what sense?  Specify a criteria.

Comment: Edited to include a criteria, sort of.

Answer (score 1):

the response body for a HTTP request can be whatever you want, really, and how you structure that depends on how your data is structured. If you want it to be easily used by a variety of consumers, converting the data to a common textual data structure is useful.

For this purpose, JSON and XML are common. JSON is probably the closest standard format for what you want. eg, `body = {1:{//object}, 2:{//anotherobject}}`, with an appropriate content type header (eg, `"application/json"` so that people using the API know by headers what the format is). I would recommend that over a list of objects with the numeric key eg `[{key:1,object:{}}]` because the default `(val,object)` mapping makes it easier to search

Depending on the language you are using, you will probably want to avoid the `myMap.toString()` type of responses and use a proper/dedicated JSON serialisation function.

Is it good practice? If the data suits the format, it's fine. These sorts of responses are common.